# android emulator WHPX: Failed to emulate MMIO access , exit code 3

Tags: android, android-emulator, amd-processor, whpx

I had Android Studio with AMD TR 2950x
android emulator was working perfectly
then suddenly it start to give me this error
with this messages :

```
10:30 AM    Emulator: qemu-system-x86_64.exe: WHPX: Failed to emulate MMIO access with EmulatorReturnStatus: 2 (InternalEmulationFailure )

10:30 AM    Emulator: qemu-system-x86_64.exe: whpx_vcpu { emulator=000000000ec95f70, window_registered=false, interruptable=true, tpr=0, apic_base=fee00900, interruption_pending=false }

10:30 AM    Emulator: qemu-system-x86_64.exe: WHV_MEMORY_ACCESS_CONTEXT { Instruction={ size=16, bytes='A1 F0 00 E0 FE 80 CC 01 A3 F0 00 E0 FE C7 05 50 ' }, AccessInfo={ AccessType=0, GpaUnmapped=1, GvaValid=0, AsUINT32=4 }, Gpa=fee000f0, Gva=0 }

10:30 AM    Emulator: qemu-system-x86_64.exe: WHPX: Failed to exec a virtual processor

10:30 AM    Emulator: Warning: QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread ((null):0, (null))

10:30 AM    Emulator: Process finished with
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As it stands it might be very hard for people to help you. Please consider editing your question to include the steps which trigger this error. Also try and provide a minimal code sample which triggers the error.

Comment: there is nothing more about it ...
every time I run the android emulator it crash

Answer (score 5):

Update Windows to insder preview build 10.0.18890

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/528337/whpx-problem-android-emulator.html

Comment: I wish this wasn't the answer. Microsoft needs to backport its Ryzen fixes for WHPX to build 18362.

Answer (score 4):

For a solution without having to join the Windows Insider Program and update to the Windows Insider Preview you can install KB4545903 directly (which is the only KB downloaded and installed by joining the release preview) which should fix the emulator issue on AMD.

Assuming you're running 64bit system, download the CAB file [here](http://download.windowsupdate.com/c/msdownload/update/software/updt/2019/07/windows10.0-kb4505903-x64_4f478eb444c5d62d5a149922cb73ab4d8098652c.cab).

Then install it with an elevated command prompt:

`DISM /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:”Full path of .cab file”`

After a restart, you should be good to go.

Props to [this medium post](https://medium.com/@lewwybogus/how-to-get-the-android-emulator-working-when-you-have-a-ryzen-processor-c3be45d96b64) for the answer.

Comment: Found this answer after approximately 3 hours of fiddling with settings and Windows Features. This works on my Ryzen with Windows 10 Pro Version 1903.

Comment: This does not work in windows 11

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error. To avoid the upgrade to the insider preview build, I did the following steps:

1. Create a new virtual device
2. Select a device
3. select a system image and go to other images
   [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygmSO.png)
4. Select an ARM based image (I've choosen the arm64-v8a API level 24)
5. Follow the next instructions and finish the setup

Now you can launch the emulator, but the emulator is **VERY SLOW**. It took about 8 minutes to go online and make it usable!

So this solution is just a quick fix, if you need to test the basics of your app. I hope, Microsoft will fix the bug and make it possible to use the HAXM/Co. again.

Hopefully this works for you as well! :)

Comment: This is a solution, however, he isn't kidding when he says it's VERY SLOW -- it's almost unusable.